# Formula with dynamic variables in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have an Inventory of boxes as an excel sheet with two columns(Total and Usage). The column on the right(total) has a value which shows the initial number of boxes. In the left column(usage) I give the number of boxes that I remove from the stock on a date. I want the right side column(Total) to be updated automatically.. Meaning if the total value at the start is 50 and I use 4 boxes then i want the cell in the total column at that row to show the new total

Example  My total value is initially 50(B2) and i use 4 boxes(A3). I want B3 to show the new total... As i keep adding usage values in column A i want column B to be updated as (previous total - new usage) How to do this in excel? I dont want to type in the formula in each cell and i dont know if i can assign varaibles to cells. Is it possible?

Comment: Kindly attach the screen shot of your sheet.

Comment: Supposedly i need 10 reputation to attach images.. I tried and failed already lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want to use subsequent rows to record each withdrawal of some boxes? You need to enter the appropriate formula in each cell of the total column. So in B3, put =B2-A3.  Then copy-paste that to all cells below in col B, Excel will paste a formula whose cell references are relative to the cell the formula is pasted to. Alternatively there is a mouse drag gesture that's even faster to fill a column with a formula.

Comment: You mean it will do it automatically?

Comment: Well, when you type in a formula into B3 like =B2-A3, what Excel actually stores behind-the-scenes is a relative formula: =[cell above] - [cell to the left]. So when that's copied to another cell it is "automatically" a formula that does the same thing with the above and left cell relative to the new cell.   If you want a formula that refers to a specific cell at some absolute location, you have to use '$', like =$B$2-$A$3.

Comment: it worked.. but i gotta copy and paste everytime.. guess i ll have to write macros if i need it to be done automatically.. thanks a lot though :)

Comment: As i mentioned, you can drag one of the corners of a cell to "stretch" a formula to more cells.

Comment: And perhaps you didn't realize that you can pre-fill column B with formulas, and then your episodes of "data entry" are just a matter of adding a value to col A, one row at a time.  If it bothers you that the formula shows values beyond the rows on which you entered data, you can revise the formula to show nothing where its A value is empty. For example: B3 cell =IF(A3>0,B2-A3,""), or better: IF(ISBLANK(A3),"",B2-A3)